# Javascript - How to get the last digit after decimal number?

Tags: javascript

e.g.,

```
var myNum = 1.208452
```

I need to get the last digit of myNum after decimal so it is (2)

Comment: Did you try something like `/\..*(\d)$/`?

Comment: I am beginner so I failed to know how to apply it. is there any sample or reference?

Comment: What if there is no decimal point? what if `myNum=100`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
var temp = myNum.toString();
var lastNum = parseInt(temp[temp.length - 1]); // it's 2
```

**Edit**

You might want to check if your number is an actual decimal, you can do:

```
var temp = myNum.toString();
if(/\d+(\.\d+)?/.test(temp)) { 
    var lastNum = parseInt(temp[temp.length - 1]);

    // do the rest
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This approach:

```
var regexp = /\..*(\d)$/;
var matches = "123.456".match(reg);
if (!matches) { alert ("no decimal point or following digits"); }
else alert(matches[1]);
```

How this works:

```
\.    : matches decimal point
.*    : matches anything following decimal point
(\d)  : matches digit, and captures it
$     : matches end of string
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in comments, I initially misunderstood your question and thought you wanted the FIRST digit after the decimal place, which is what this one-liner does:

```
result = Math.floor((myNum - Math.floor(myNum)) * 10);
```

If you want a purely mathematical solution that gives you the LAST digit after the decimal place you can transform the number until the last digit is the first one after the decimal place and THEN use the above code, like this (but it's no longer a nice one-liner):

```
temp = myNum;
while( Math.floor(temp) != temp ) temp *= 10;
temp /= 10;
result = Math.floor((temp- Math.floor(temp)) * 10);
```

How it works:

the above code multiplies temp by 10 until there is nothing after the decimal place, then divides by 10 to yield a number with only a single digit after the decimal place then uses my original code to give you the first digit after the decimal place! Phew!

Comment: Thank you anyway. your code was helpful with other method.

Answer (score -2):

Just do:

```
function lastdigit(a)
{
    return a % 10;
}
```

Comment: the result of lastdigit(1.2) will be 1.2, not 2 like the OP said

Comment: Ok doesnt work with decimals but with integers its fine